# cannot open iphone build

Tags: iphone, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created an ios application which supports both iphone and ipad
I have created provisioning profiles, and installed it correctly. (process following in iphone apps)

Even i am able to debug the app using development profile. but unfortunately when i am trying to  install the app using  Ad-Hoc environment to my ipad.  without any error it install successfully . but i cannot open the app. its closing. (i have already tried the test flight)

Any particular reason anyone know

I need to  add some modifications to above post
This application is an universal app. and iphone app is not working (crashing). is thr any thng do i have to do create the build for ipad 
Thanks

Hi guys found the problem, i took the .app file from the reveal and it worked. Thanks

Comment: try installing via .app & provisioning instead of .ipa through itunes

Comment: samfisher -: Did the same thing at the same time  . Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an Ad-Hoc enabled distribution provisioning profile to sign the application?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html

Also make sure that your current devices is added to this profile (bullet 6 in the above link).

Comment: This cannot be the reason, I believe else it wouldn't even have installed on the device

Comment: OK, try to remove the app. Switch the phone off, then on and try installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Architecture, you have built the app with. Your device should support that architecture